# Drop Tables After Backup Migrate Restore

Tags: 7, entities, nodes, database, backups

I find myself using Backup and Migrate's Restore (from manual backups folder) when testing module sets or after a change to a project is problematic. I use Schema after the restore to check for extra tables left in the database during the restore process. Generally,  orphaned extra tables that are no longer wanted, needed or an issue are tables from modules or entity/content type fields being prototyped/tested. Module tables left in the database cause PDO Exception errors if I attempt to reinstall same module or alternate dev version after a restore. Extra field tables can get quite numerous and chaotic when rapid prototyping.

**EXAMPLE**
Match (107)
Hide Extra (11)
Tables in the database that are not present in the schema. This indicates previously installed modules that are disabled but not un-installed or modules that do not use the Schema API.

Schema report looks like:

- Match (107) Tables for which the schema and database agree.
- Extra () Tables in the database that are not present in the schema. This indicates previously installed modules that are disabled but not un-installed or modules that do not use the Schema API.

  ```
  field_data_field_test_termsfruits   // fields for content types
  field_data_field_test_code_and_api
  field_data_field_test_drupal
  field_revision_test_termsfruits
  field_revision_test_terms_code_and_api
  field_revision_test_terms_drupal
  search_api_index                    // a module not being used
  search_api_item
  search_api_server
  search_api_task
  ```

Seems that Backup and Migrate team is not ready to include drop tables options and the issue has been discussed in detail. I've also tried the Demonstration module which was great in D6 but just spits errors in D7 for me.

Aside from phpMyAdmin, MySQL GUI tools or command line to drop tables (and realizing security risk if permissions are compromised), what contributed modules or other PHP/API methods can I use from within the Drupal interface to drop specific tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the API goes there's [`db_drop_table()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_drop_table/7)

```
db_drop_table('table_name');
```

Comment: How could it be used with forms to make a modules that you could type in the table name(s) to drop?

Comment: I suppose that after restore, and after checking schema I can use a php block with that function.